# Laravel on MAMP every time I create a new view, I have to CHMOD storage/views to 777, then 775

Tags: php, view, mamp, laravel, chmod

I am working through Shawn McCool's book (great book) and each time I create a new view, and try to load it, I get a permissions error.

I am wondering why the views generated don't have read permissions. The odd thing is if I `chmod` to 775, I still get the error, I have to 777 then 775.

Can anyone shed some light on this and why it's happening?

Thanks!

Edit:

Error after adding new view

```
file_put_contents(/Users/jason/Sites/laravel1/storage/views/5c4b7b4707d658dffe52d481be6c680e): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Permissions on storage/views
drwxrwxr-x@  7 jason  jason  238 Mar  7 17:15 views
```

Permissions on new view 
`-rw-r--r--`

Error after `chmod 775 views`

```
 file_put_contents(/Users/jason/Sites/laravel1/storage/views/5c4b7b4707d658dffe52d481be6c680e): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Permissions after `chmod 775 views`

```
drwxrwxr-x@  7 jason  jason  238 Mar  7 17:15 views
```

After `chmod 777 views`, it works

```
drwxrwxrwx@  8 jason  jason  272 Mar  7 17:25 views
```

After `chmod 777 views` it still works

```
drwxrwxr-x@  8 jason  jason  272 Mar  7 17:25 views
```

But here is the twist, I did not have this issue if I didn't use viewname.blade.php. If I did viewname.php, there was no error. It seems to have something to do with Blade.

### Edit 2:

Related: always make sure to .gitignore these files so that you don't end up with cached views, etc. getting pulled onto your server from your dev environment.

Comment: If permission is set to 775 then it is...

Comment: @jtheman I don't follow. This is the behavior I am experiencing. I have to reset the permissions on the views dir each time. If I go straight to 775, I still get the error.

Comment: @shapeshifter is is in fact umask. It's set to 0022. Any idea how to overcome this without having to CHMOD each time I create a new view? And maybe answer the question since that is at least the root of my issue.

Comment: The problem doesn't really make sense.  You are overwriting the previous 777 with 775.  So the permissions are the same as just doing 775 first.  See what the actual permissions on the file are, ls -la thefile between each chmod.

Comment: You're right, it does not make sense. Regardless, when I add a new view, I get file_put_contents(/Users/jason/Sites/laravel1/storage/views/viewname): failed to open stream: Permission denied

If I CHMOD 775 views and reload I get the same error. The CHMOD 777 and it works, then CHMOD 775 and it still works. I am about to paste the steps above in an edit.

Comment: Apache isn't running as the user "jason" it's running as "httpd" or "apache". `chown -R jason:apache /Users/jason/Sites`

Comment: Invalid argument was returned. But this points me in the right direction.

Comment: @Jason If you use the blade engine, your storage folder is utilised to hold a cached copy of the view, hence your permission problems. Without the blade engine, the view is just `eval`'d and then returned with no storage / cache mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since (I think) Lion, the web server does not use `mod_userdir` anymore, so apache does not run as your user but as `_www` instead, see

```
user:~$ ps ax -o pid,user,rgroup,comm | grep -Ee "PID|httpd"
  PID USER             RGID COMM
10317 root                0 /usr/sbin/httpd
16516 _www               70 /usr/sbin/httpd
18497 _www               70 /usr/sbin/httpd
...
```

Now for your folder with permissions `775`, user `jason` and group `jason`

```
drwxrwxr-x@ 7 jason jason 238 Mar 7 17:15 storage/views
```

Laravel will try to create a cache file for every blade view in that folder. If no such file exists, it will try to create that automatically. This requires *write access* to the folder, and since Apache runs as `_www` it requires write access on that directory as *other*.

Once the file exists however, that file is owned by `_www`, and so Apache does not require write access to the `storage/views` directory anymore. Until a new view is created...

Now what you can do is:

(keep in mind that there are other caches too in `storage` other than `storage/views`, so everything here is done on the whole `storage` folder)

- either set the `storage` directory to `777` (for development this is "ok")

  ```
  chmod -R 777 storage
  ```
- Or (better) `chown` the `storage` directory to `jason:_www`, this way you can keep the `775` permissions and both you and apache have sufficient access.

  ```
  sudo chown -R jason:_www storage
  ```

Comment: Thank you, that was the exact solution (2nd option)

Comment: This shouldn't have anything to do with Git, the issue was that the OSX apache does not run as your user and so can't write in the cache/storage directory. Though you are right in that cache and storage should not be in version control - in any project.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I didn't take the time to re-read my orig question and mistook it for another issue. Edited!